# how to make an array of elements made inside a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I need to make an array of these zombies and their x and y coordinates, which are randomly chosen inside a for loop. I need this array to delete or change their place if needed in the next steps.

```cpp
while (true) {

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    drawGrid(renderer, n, 2500, 128, 128, 128, 10);
    drawGrid(renderer, n, 100, 0, 0, 0, 50);

   
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        int x = rand() % n * 50;
        int y = rand() % n * 50;
        drawAgent(renderer, x, y, 255, 0, 0); // Zombie (red)
        
    }
```

I tried to make a (int** zArray) outside of for loop but it didn work because the x and y weren't defined out side of for loop

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Assume we know nothing about what the rest of your program looks like.

Comment: How about classes, objects and `std::vector`?

Comment: `int **zArray` declares a pointer, not an array.   Although pointers can be treated *as if* they are an array *in some contexts*, they are actually different things.

Comment: None of the drawing functions should be necessary for what you describe in your text. At a guess, your [mre] should look more like ``int main() { int** zArray; /* How should this be declared? */ for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) { int x = rand() % n * 50; int y = rand() % n * 50; /* I need to store this `x` and `y` in `zArray`. */ } }`` -- Include only what is necessary and dummy-up (and annotate with comments) the parts you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a type to hold the data you need for each zombie

```
struct zombie {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

With that, you can declare a collection of zombies, and add to that collection in your loop.

```
std::vector<zombie> zombies;

for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    int x = rand() % n * 50;
    int y = rand() % n * 50;
    drawAgent(renderer, x, y, 255, 0, 0); // Zombie (red)
    zombies.push_back({ x, y });
}

// Now use zombies
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator would be better than the above rand() function.

```
std::random_device rdev;
std::mt19937 mt(rdev())
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,50);

for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    int x = dist(mt);
    int y = dist(mt);
    drawAgent(renderer, x, y, 255, 0, 0); // Zombie (red)
    zombies.push_back({ x, y });
}
```